# Can't call a function even with typeof type guard

Tags: typescript

```
function func<T>(param: T | (() => T)) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    return typeof param === "function" ? param() : param;
}
```

Even with the `typeof` type guard, I can't invoke `param` and this is only when I have a generic function, it works otherwise:

```
function func(param: string | (() => string)) {
    return typeof param === "function" ? param() : param;
}
```

I've no clue as to why this is happening and what's the fix, I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a type guard that checks if the param is a function or not.

```
function isFunction (arg: unknown): arg is Function {
  return typeof arg === "function"
}
```

and then you can use it like this

```
function func<T>(param: T | (() => T)) {
    return isFunction(param) ? param() : param;
}
```

You can see this in action in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMXNeSAUBDAJwHMAuRcAazDgHcwBKMwo5FRDSWBRAbwChEiAgFMoIAkigBPAA7C4wRM0QBeNYgBEoTtg18Avnz7as3EwB4AKgD4cMwngC2ZS4gA+iHDnqrriS-Q+-IKCImISrBymYHYOjj4A-Ij2BE7eiGQpTgDcBkYQCChwADbCAHTFcEQ4JjgALABMgXwFYEWlFVU1mF4+Kn4aKFAEMGAswARwjogAFsIiGoFAA)